# Export Matlab Figure to LaTeX

Tags: matlab, latex

I am trying to use an open source Matlab figure exporter called [fig2texPS](http://fig2texps.peter-scholz.net/Sources/fig2texPS.html) but I can't seem to get it to work, the documentation says I have to get the figure number of the figure I want to export then call

```
fig2tex(myFigureNumber)
```

but I don't know how to get the so-called "figure number".Does anyone have some experience with this project or someone who can understand this [documentation](http://fig2texps.peter-scholz.net/Sources/fig2texPS.html) guide me on how to use it?

UPDATE: Tried plotting a function then getting the figure number from the figure window but it still does not work.Can you please clarify a bit more on how I would get the "figure handle"?

```
x = 1:1:10;
y = 1:1:10;
plot(x,y);
fig2tex(1); //Undefined function 'fig2tex' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the figure *handle*, which you can get when you make the figure (`myFigureNumber = figure;`), or with `gcf` if the figure is active/current, or with other functions.  However, most of the time you will see it right here:

[image]

**EDIT**: For your updated error message, the error is because MATLAB can't find `fig2tex` (should be `fig2texPS`). Find the path to fig2texPS.m and add it to your path with `addpath C:\path\to\fig2texfolder` where that file lives. Verify that it works with `which fig2texPS`.

Comment: Taking the figure number from the figure window doesn't work for me, Please see update.

Comment: @KillaKem It's because it's not on the path. See my other comment. You need to add it to your MATLAB "path" with `addpath`, or change the directory to that path.

Comment: Thanks, function was called 'fig2texPS' but I was making calls to 'fig2tex'.